# Angular 5 HttpClient Firefox PUT not executed but works in Chrome

Tags: angular, typescript, httpclient, put

Im creating a website right now using Angular 5 and CouchDB. In my database.service.ts a method looks like this:

```
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
const auth = my database adress;
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

createUser(id: string, email_: string, password_: string, firstname: string, surname_: string, role: string): any {
    const obj: object = {
      name: firstname, surname: surname_, role, email: email_, password: password_, theme: 'indigo', projects: {}, widgets: {}
    };

    return this.http.put(auth + '/' + id, JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)))
      .map((res: Response) => res);
  }
```

And im calling the method when the user should be created like this:

```
 this.databaseService.createUser(id, email, password, firstname, surname, this.role)
        .subscribe(result => {},
          err => {
            console.log(err);
            alert('No connection to database available!');
          });
```

This works absolutely fine in Chrome but not in Firefox! The PUT did not even get executed in Firefox so it can't be a problem with the CouchDB (i captured the traffic via wireshark and npcap). GET and POST works fine in firefox, but PUT not. The headers look got ("Accept":  'application/json' etc..) and i have no clue whats's wrong.

It should be at least executing, or am i wrong?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What do you see in the development console or network tab in the browser? Also why do you do this `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))` ? You should be able to just pass `obj` directly without converting it to a string and then back to an object.

Comment: Ah yes that's what i forgot haha, the console log says "message: "Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error"
​
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
​
ok: false
​
status: 0
​
statusText: "Unknown Error"

Comment: `unknown url` ? Log what the request URL is before you make it to see if it is valid. Also HttpClient works with the deserialized json directly unless you specify otherwise in the options, mapping the response as `Response` is not valid. If you are not returning anything then you have to specify `responseType`:"text" in the request options.

Comment: The couchDB answers with a json, if i put "responseType: 'application/json'" or "responseType: 'text'" it says "405 method not allowed" in chrome, in firefox it's still not working. I think this wouldn't explain why the PUT don't get executed? Thanks for your help, i will remove the stringify stuff :D

Comment: Ah and the url looks correct when i log it to the console directly before the "return http.put ..."

Answer (score 0):

You should try specifying the `content-type` header explicitly. I had a similar problem with the old client and that solved the problem

```
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'content-type':  'application/json'
  })
};
// ...
this.http.put(auth + '/' + id, obj, httpOptions);
```

Comment: Hey, thanks. Unfortunately the error stays ""Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error"
​
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
​
ok: false
​
status: 0
​
statusText: "Unknown Error"
​
url: null"

Comment: nope, the PUT doesn't even get executed in firefox (in dev tools network tab and i watched the traffic via wireshark). in chrome it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem :D
The "auth" Url to the couchDB was
`http://username:password@127.0.0.1:5984/my_database`

Firefox interpretes this in a wrong way (i absolutely don't know why!) but when i do it without authentification, it works.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

In my case the WebAPI was being run locally. It worked fine in chrome, but had no response using Firefox.

Turns out Firefox did not trust the self-signed security certificate. Just open the WebAPI directly, ie https://localhost:3000 in Firefox, then confirm the security exception.

That solved the issue for me.